I'm trying to make a slow loading effect but I've run into a problem
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let img = document.querySelector('.logosection-logo');
    let timer = 0;
    let inset = 0

    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            img.style.clipPath = 'inset(0 0 ' + inset + '% 0)';
        }, timer);
        inset = 100 - i*10
        timer += 100;
        console.log(timer, i*10, inset)
    }
});

it doesnt working at all somebody know how to fix it?
as i understand the error is related to async, i am new to js

Perhaps you should use keyframes as these are great for animations on page load. Here is an example where the image 'loads' from top to bottom using your clip-path idea:


@keyframes clipIn{
   0% {
      clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 0 0);
      opacity: 0;
   }
   100% {
      clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
      opacity: 1;
   }
 }
figure{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.logosection-logo{
   animation: clipIn 4s ease-in-out;
   opacity: 1;
   display: inline-block;
}
img{
   height: 320px;
   width: auto;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Image loader</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <main>
         <figure class="logosection-logo">
            <img src="https://media.newyorker.com/photos/669324fd14c38da9ac7b7815/master/w_1920,c_limit/Trump-shot-AP24195851874181.jpg" alt="Trmp shooting" />
            <figcaption>Trump Shot</figcaption>
         </figure>
      </main>
   </body>
</html>



You can modify the animation: clipIn 4s ease-in-out; css property of the logosection-logo class to play with timing effects and change the clip-path: polygon values of the clipIn keyframe to suit your needs.
If you really want to use setTimeout then just move it into it's own function and call it in the for loop like so:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   let img = document.querySelector('.logosection-logo');
   let timer = 0;
   let inset = 0

   for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      pause(timer, img, inset);
      inset = 100 - i*10
      timer += 100;
      //console.log(timer, i*10, inset)
   }
});
function pause(timer, img, inset){
      setTimeout(() => {
      img.style.clipPath = 'inset(0 0 ' + inset + '% 0)';
   }, timer);
}
img{
   height: 320px;
   width: auto;
   clip-path: inset(0 0 0% 0)
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Image loader</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <main>
         <figure class="logosection-logo">
            <img src="https://media.newyorker.com/photos/669324fd14c38da9ac7b7815/master/w_1920,c_limit/Trump-shot-AP24195851874181.jpg" alt="Trmp shooting" />
            <figcaption>Trump Shot</figcaption>
         </figure>
      </main>
   </body>
</html>




thank u so much
